# SQL select for a specific node all subnodes

Tags: mysql, select, hierarchy

I'm using mySQL on phpMyAdmin, my table is

```
| code | name | parent |
|------|------|--------|
|  10  |node10|   5    |
|  5   |node05|   2    |
```

where 5 is the parent of 10 (which is also a node), I need to select for a specific node A all childs and subchilds until the last leaf, I tried to do that but I've got also 2 levels of subchilds (for example for node 2 I've got 5 and 10)

```
SELECT * 
FROM `composant` 
WHERE parent IN( 
    SELECT code 
    FROM `composant` 
    WHERE parent=2 OR code=2
)
```

so how can we get loop to get all the subnodes ?

Comment: If I understand well, you need recursivity to do that. This can be done either by (_recursive_) user-defined-functions (which can be done in mySQL), or by using `RECURSIVE Common-Table-Expressions`. AFAIK, MariaDB offers CTEs, but MySQL 5.7 does not. Check [How to do the Recursive SELECT query in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql)